# Maven android - merge different android project

Tags: android, maven

can i merge three maven android project into a single one using maven ?

thanks

regards

Comment: you can put the different three projects into one but i'm not sure if this makes sense...The other question: What's the relationship to Maven ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the three projects are Android Library projects (`<packaging>apklib</packaging>`), you should be able to collect them into a single Android Application project (`<packaging>apk</packaging>`).

Using Maven Android Plugin version 2.9.0-beta-2 or later, you should be able to accomplish that.

Here are the release notes for 2.9.0-beta-1:
http://groups.google.com/group/maven-android-developers/browse_thread/thread/e7978fbf4e4b85f0?pli=1

This is where the `apklib` support in maven-android-plugin is documented:
http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/ApkLib 
(be sure to read up on Google's official Android Library documentation which is linked from there too)

Look at the changelog for the latest version to use:
http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Changelog

Comment: thank you very much ... i don't need it anymore because i refactored my project to be a single one ... but i try out this solution ...